# How to overload operator ->* in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, smart-pointers

Is there a way to overload `->*` for use with a smart-pointer-like object?  Below is what I would like to do.  For simplicity I'm not using templates (I'll get to that once I have it working for a single fixed class). I can get it to work with pointers to data members, but I can't seem to get it right for pointers to member functions.  For the time being, I'm willing to settle for an overload that only works for member functions (and not for data members).  I'm even willing to settle for an overload that only accepts pointers to member functions with a single fixed prototype (such as `void func()`).

```
struct MyObject
{
   void MyMethod() {}
};

struct MySmartPtr {
   MyObject *p;

   // What should the prototype and function body be?
   // ??? operator->*(????) { ???? }
};

void MyFunc()
{
   MyObject obj;
   MySmartPtr obj_ptr;
   obj_ptr.p = &obj;
   void (MyObject::* member_func_ptr)() = &MyObject::MyMethod;

   // Now call obj.MyMethod() through the "smart pointer"
   (obj_ptr->*member_func_ptr)();
}
```

Please don't offer me workarounds (e.g., overload `*` and do `(*obj_ptr.*member_func_ptr)()`).  I want `->*` to work as indicated in the code snippet.

Comment: @Tobias: The article linked to in my answer explains that as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Oct_1999.pdf) by Scott Meyers. It's quite old, but the only resource discussing overloading `->*` that I know of.

Note that the standard library's iterator and smart pointer types don't overload `->*`. I don't know the reasons, but I suspect it's because that operator rarely ever used, is a lot of hassle to implement, and it's easy to work around it. Anyway, since the standard library doesn't support it, your users won't expect it to work either.

Comment: Interesting article, but quite disappointing in that it seems that a functor must be returned.  I like it not.

Answer (score 1):

http://codepad.org/yl3Ghwab

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct OBJ {
  typedef void (OBJ::*Met)(void);
  void met( void ) {
    printf( "Method call!\n" );
  }
};

struct POBJ {
  OBJ* p;
  typedef void (*fun)(void);
  static void nop( void ) {}
  fun operator->*( OBJ::Met m ) {
    printf( "operator ->* !\n" );
//    return fun(p->*m); // works in gcc
    (p->*m)();
    return nop;
  }
};

int main( void ) {
  OBJ obj;
  OBJ* pobj = &obj;
  POBJ p; p.p = &obj;
  OBJ::Met met = &OBJ::met;
  (pobj->*met)();
  (p->*met)();
}
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B for prototypes

Comment: Well, strictly speaking this indeed satisfies the requirements I set forth, but having the operator function do the actual invocation and returning NOP is not what I intended.  I suspect this solution will not extend to arbitrary prototypes.  The `return fun(p->*m)` looks like what I was after but doesn't really work because it returns a pointer to a standalone function (one that doesn't take a `this` pointer, so is unable to access the class's data members).  If I add data members to `OBJ` and have `met` try to access them I get a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a shot with C++0x: variadic templates, bind and function. I guess it should be possible to port it to boost:

```
#include <iostream>                                                             
#include <functional>                                                           

struct S
{       
  void f()
  {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  }
};

template<class C>
struct PMFSmartPtr
{
  C *p;
  template<typename C1, typename R, typename... P>
  std::function<R(P...)> operator->*(R (C1::*pmf)(P...))
  {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    return(std::function<R(P...)>(std::bind(pmf, p)));
  }
};

int main()
{
  PMFSmartPtr<S> x;
  void (S::*pmf)() = &S::f;
  (x->*pmf)();
  return(0);
}
```

Tried on g++ 4.4.4 and works for functions not taking any arguments, for 1 argument member function compilation fails but I do not know if this is my fault or compiler or libstdc++ issue...